# ffmpeg: does 2 step encoding solves issues during video conversion?

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg

I'm encoding several videos to x265 format to save disk storage, and on some of them some errors happen. Like these ones below:

```
[h264 @ 0x285f800] error while decoding MB 15 15, bytestream -29ate=3310.7kbits/s
[h264 @ 0x285f800] concealing 2434 DC, 2434 AC, 2434 MV errors in P frame
[matroska,webm @ 0x22205e0] Read error at pos. 1932044330 (0x7328a82a)
[h264 @ 0x27890c0] illegal short term buffer state detected
[h264 @ 0x27890c0] Missing reference picture, default is 65694
[h264 @ 0x27d0880] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 0x27d0880] error while decoding MB 63 29, bytestream -8rate=3230.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=1
[h264 @ 0x27d0880] concealing 1266 DC, 1266 AC, 1266 MV errors in P frame
[matroska,webm @ 0x22205e0] Read error at pos. 2048927876 (0x7a202884)
[h264 @ 0x27304e0] mmco: unref short failureime=00:48:51.54 bitrate=3229.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=1
[h264 @ 0x27890c0] error while decoding MB 28 35, bytestream -16ate=3177.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=1
[h264 @ 0x27890c0] concealing 821 DC, 821 AC, 821 MV errors in P frame
[matroska,webm @ 0x22205e0] Read error at pos. 2112109973 (0x7de43d95)
[h264 @ 0x285f800] mmco: unref short failureime=00:50:36.21 bitrate=3175.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=1
[h264 @ 0x27d0880] error while decoding MB 51 21, bytestream -28ate=3199.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=1
[h264 @ 0x27d0880] concealing 1918 DC, 1918 AC, 1918 MV errors in P frame
[matroska,webm @ 0x22205e0] Read error at pos. 2202555497 (0x83485469)
[matroska,webm @ 0x22205e0] Read error at pos. 2409903171 (0x8fa43443)306.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=1
[h264 @ 0x27d0880] error while decoding MB 3 30, bytestream -7
[h264 @ 0x27d0880] concealing 1246 DC, 1246 AC, 1246 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x27890c0] error while decoding MB 7 5, bytestream -7bitrate=3396.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=1
[h264 @ 0x27890c0] concealing 3242 DC, 3242 AC, 3242 MV errors in B frame
[matroska,webm @ 0x22205e0] Read error at pos. 2628527465 (0x9cac2569)
[h264 @ 0x285f800] mmco: unref short failuretime=01:02:15.08 bitrate=3396.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=1
[h264 @ 0x2818040] error while decoding MB 36 30, bytestream -12rate=3473.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=1
[h264 @ 0x2818040] concealing 1213 DC, 1213 AC, 1213 MV errors in P frame
[matroska,webm @ 0x22205e0] Read error at pos. 2874947326 (0xab5c36fe)
[h264 @ 0x27890c0] error while decoding MB 46 8, bytestream -6itrate=3590.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=1
[h264 @ 0x27890c0] concealing 2963 DC, 2963 AC, 2963 MV errors in B frame
[matroska,webm @ 0x22205e0] Read error at pos. 3162785874 (0xbc844852)
```

If I add 2-step encoding, that can fix these errors? What exactly does 2-step encoding does? The command I'm using is pretty much the one on this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/718300/396175 so how (which parameter) should I use to apply 2-step encoding?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the input possibly "lossy" every so often or something?

Comment: Can't be sure because they are mostly TV Shows and movies downloaded from the internet. They all play fine with VLC without crashes or stops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm encoding several videos to x265 format to save disk storage, and on some of them some errors happen.

Looks like decoding errors. The input has something wrong with it so the errors show up when the file is being read. If the input plays fine, or if the output looks ok, then ignore them.

> If I add 2-step encoding, that can fix these errors?

No. It's a decoding issue. However, your `ffmpeg` is old so consider [downloading](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) a new one and seeing if it is more robust in its decoding (probably not but you never know).

> What exactly does 2-step encoding does?

I see no mention of 2-pass encoding in the link you provided. I assume by "2-step" you are referring to "2-pass", but correct me if I am mistaken. 2-pass encoding generally is used to target a specific output file size. Otherwise, just use a single pass with encoders that offer a *constant rate factor* such as x264 and x265. See FFmpeg Wiki: [H.264](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) & [H.265](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265) for more info on that.

> (which parameter) should I use to apply 2-step encoding?

2-pass is initiated by using the `-pass` option. See the wiki links above for examples. However, you don't need to perform 2-pass encoding. Just use `-crf` as shown in the link you provided.

Comment: So 2-pass is just to set a specific file size? I think I'm using the default ffmpeg version that comes with ubuntu 16.04. Great answer! VERY complete.

Comment: @Vini.g.fer Basically, yes. I almost never use 2-pass.

Comment: @Vini.g.fer All things being equal x265 is slower than x264–part of the tradeoff for more efficient compression.